# Jumping to previous position in TeXshop

Tags: texshop

I would like to be able to "jump to the previous position" of the cursor in TeXshop. This is useful for scrolling up, checking the name of a label, and then jumping back to where you were editing. How can I do this?

Comment: The title of your question and its content are quite disjoint. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the error.

Comment: I just use click the "double-window" view button on the top right hand side which gives me two independent views of the same file. That was one portion of the  window stays at the source and I can move the other portion of the window to the destination so never loose my original position in the file.

Comment: That's a nifty method, thanks. Still looking for an answer though. I've found macros eg. at http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2011-May/046997.html but I haven't been able to get them working.